# Difference between statsmodel OLS vs scikit linear regression

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression, statsmodels

I have a question about two different methods from different libraries which seems doing same job. I am trying to make linear regression model.

Here is the code which I using statsmodel library with OLS :

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=1)

x_train = sm.add_constant(X_train)
model = sm.OLS(y_train, x_train)
results = model.fit()

print "GFT + Wiki / GT  R-squared", results.rsquared
```

This print out **GFT + Wiki / GT  R-squared 0.981434611923**

and the second one is scikit learn library Linear model method:

```
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions = model.predict(X_test)

print 'GFT + Wiki / GT R-squared: %.4f' % model.score(X_test, y_test)
```

This print out **GFT + Wiki / GT R-squared: 0.8543**

So my question is the both method prints our R^2 result but one is print out 0.98 and the other one is 0.85.

From my understanding, OLS works with training dataset. So my questions,

- Is there a way that work with test data set with OLS ?
- Is the traning data set score gives us any meaning(In OLS we didn't use test data set)? From my past knowledge we have to work with test data.
- What is the difference between OLS and scikit linear regression. Which one we use for calculating the score of the model ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: duplicate/cross-posting from http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/146804/difference-between-statsmodel-ols-and-scikit-linear-regression

Comment: yes I know, but I cannot understand clearly the difference

Comment: If you had written code that I can copy and paste, ie which also generates some synthetic data, then that would make it easier for anybody trying to answer your question. My hunch is that statsmodels uses classical r^2 whereas sklearn uses predictive r^2 on held out data, which is generally lower.